# derivation of the integral without induction

Tags: integration

$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^k \theta d\theta = \frac{\pi ^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma( \frac{n-1}{2}+1)} $$

I saw the derivations online using mathematical induction, but does anyone know how to derive this say I did not know the result of this integral ?

Comment: Geometrically, I think this is the surface area of an $n$ dimensional sphere. Set up the integral in the proper spherical coordinates and you will retrieve the integral on the left.

Comment: im not really interested in how the left hand side comes to be, im more interested in how that integral can give a closed form expression in terms of pi and the gamma function ..

Comment: ...you can use the already existing formula for the surface area to work backwards. Start with the right side, and then prove it can be represented as the integral on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ninad Munshi pointed out in the comment, this relates to the multidimensional volume elements in spherical coordinates. So to get to the result, you'd need to use the beta and gamma functions. The sine function integral is related to the beta function which is related to the gamma function.

The Beta function has an integral form defined as:

$$B(x,y) = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2x-1}(\theta)cos^{2y-1}(\theta) d\theta$$

making $2x-1 = k$ (since we want to relate this to your original integral, which is over sine to the power of $k$), when $y=\frac{1}{2}$ the cosine disappears and the integral can be simplified to:

$$B(\frac{k+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^k d\theta$$

Since our original integral is from $0$ to $\pi$, let's adjust the limits of the beta integration:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(\theta) d\theta = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^k d\theta = B(\frac{k+1}{2})$$

So now we have successfully demonstrated how the integral relates to the bet function.

The Beta function is related to the gamma function as:

$$B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Plugging in our values for $x$ and $y$ we get:

$$B(\frac{k+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2} + 1)}$$

The gamma function has the property that $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$ and $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = sqrt(\pi)$.

Now, we would use the fact that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$ and can be taken out of the product to simplify the product of gamma functions and multiply all integrals from $k=1$ to $n-1$.

The product of gamma functions for consecutive half-integer arguments simplifies due to the recursive nature of the gamma function, and you will eventually reach:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2} + 1)} = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}}{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2} +1)}$$

Remembering that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = sqrt(\pi)$ we have:

$$\frac{\pi ^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma( \frac{n-1}{2}+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Noting that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^k \theta d \theta & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)-1} \theta \cos ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{k+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore we have
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_0^\pi \sin ^k \theta d \theta= \pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{4}{2}\right) \cdots \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma(2) \Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}\right) \cdots \Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}+1\right)}= \frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}+1\right)}
$$